# R: drawing of incomplete monochrome picture

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, drawing, raster

I've got an image which descibed as this set of data:

```
0    49.5    -3
...
50    101    15
```

Columns describes: (1) X coordinate; (2) Y coordinate; and (3) shade of gray (deviation from the mean) respectively.
My problem is that the set of points doesn't fill rectangle (and this set will be divided into subsets), so I can't use something like this (100 and 202 are width and height of picture):

```
m <- matrix(dataset[[3]],100,202)
image(m)
```

Is there any way to direct drawing this image without any transformation of dataset, or maybe only with transformation of shade of gray column?

Comment: Make the missing values explicit firs, with e.g. `tidyr::complete`. You'll probably have to transform, unless you use `ggplot` instead.

Comment: And how can I use ggplot here?

Comment: See [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_tile.html).

Comment: Thanks, it worked and I'll add the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to [Axeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4341440/axeman), the solution is here: suppose, we have imagedata:

```
> imagedata
    V1    V2  V3
1      0.0  49.5  -3
2      0.0  50.0   3
...
333    1.5  58.0  -4
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 10273 rows ]
```

We do the following to print it:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- imagedata[[1]]
y <- imagedata[[2]]
z <- imagedata[[3]]
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = z))
```

And this image will be showed.